# Is creating navigational relationships in database bad practice?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I'm using EF4.3/Sql Server 2008 Web.

I've tried to create a normalised database - here's a section of it:

[image]

As you can see the common factor is that they are all linked via BuyerId. In EF, I can navigate across this structure using "Buyer.MatchBuyer.MatchNodes" etc, however I wondered whether it was considered bad practice to create additional relationships purely for the purpose of further simplifying this navigation.

For instance adding a relationahip between LenderMatchNode and Buyer on BuyerId.

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is really not a good idea to do in the database. If you are using entity framework you can use "Table Splitting" to achieve the same functionality without having to use an odd database structure.

This is a good tutorial:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx

And there are others on Scott Guthrie's blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/

EDIT: Here is the tutorial I mentioned:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

You can check scenario three. I think that is what you were after.

EDIT: Gert Arnolds comment made me re-think a little.

Could be as follows:

**Buyer**

```
BuyerId
Name
Status
BuyerTypeId
RequestClass
AcceptQuota
TierId
Commission
```

**MatchNode**

```
BuyerId
TierId
Enabled
RuleClass
```

You then have 1:N for Buyer-MatchNode and possibly composite key on Buyer?

In the EF you can use afrmentioned table splitting to provide the navigational properties you are looking for. Of course it probably won't make a huge amount of difference but I guess it's a matter of what approach you prefer.

Comment: I don't think this is about Table Splitting.

Comment: @GertArnold Looks like it to me. The 4 tables above could be a single table (and probably should be). But dotnetnoob wants to have navigation properties which simplyfy the model.

Comment: Good point, didn't notice that. However the Buyer-MatchBuyer and LenderMatchNode-Buyer could still be done with splitting.

Comment: The Buyer-MatchBuyer relationship is split because Buyer is common to all buyers but MatchBuyer is only relevant to buyers with a BuyerType of "Match". There is also a CompareBuyer with its own unique fields. Data in MatchBuyer is constrained by a trigger. This is also the same for LenderMatchNode-MatchNode.

Comment: Ok, not necessarily suggesting this is a good idea but if you have several types such as MatchBuyer, CompareBuyer then you can use inheritance to provide a single table but multiple different entity types. An example of this can be found in MS "Employee Tracker" sample. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ef4/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4279 I found this quite useful but again it depends on how you like to do things. It seems like you original question asked about creating purely navigational relationships but actually they are a bit more than that.